# import problem with twisted.web server

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I'm just getting started with twisted.web, and I'm having trouble importing a Python module into a `.rpy` script.

in `C:\py\twisted\mysite.py`, I have this:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web import server

class MySite(Resource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.write("<!DOCTYPE html>")
        request.write("<html><head>")
        request.write("<title>Twisted Driven Site</title>")
        request.write("</head><body>")
        request.write("<h1>Twisted Driven Website</h1>")
        request.write("<p>Prepath: <pre>{0}</pre></p>".format(request.prepath))
        request.write("</body></html>")
        request.finish()
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```

and in `C:\py\twisted\index.rpy`, I have this:

```
import mysite
reload(mysite)

resource = mysite.MySite()
```

I ran `twistd -n web --port 8888 --path C:\py\twisted` in command prompt and the server started successfully. But when I requested `localhost:8888` I got a (huge) stack trace originating from an ImportError:

`<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named mysite`

I can import the module from the interpreter, and if i just execute `index.rpy` as a python script, I don't get the import error. The documentation on this subject is a bit vague, it just says "However, it is often a better idea to define Resource subclasses in Python modules. In order for changes in modules to be visible, you must either restart the Python process, or reload the module:" (from [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#rpys)).

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you need to set PYTHONPATH to include `C:\py\twisted`.

Long answer...

An rpy script *is* basically just some Python code, like any other Python code.  So an import in a rpy script works just like an import in any other Python code.  For the most common case, this means that the directories in `sys.path` are visited one by one, in order, and if a `.py` file matching the imported name is found, that file is used to define the module.

`sys.path` is mostly populated from a static definition including things like C:\Python26\Lib\  and from the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  However, there's one extra thing worth knowing about.  When you run "python", the current working directory is added to the front of `sys.path`.  When you run "python C:\foo\bar\baz.py", `C:\foo\bar\' is added to the front of`sys.path`.  But when you run "twistd ...", nothing useful is added to`sys.path`.

This last behavior probably explains why your tests work if you run the rpy script directly, or if you run python and try to import the module interactively, but fail when you use twistd.  Adding `C:\py\twisted` to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable should make the module importable when the rpy script is run from the server you start with twistd.

Comment: This is an excellent answer for a simple problem. I guess this whole time I was just not-so-blissfully unaware of `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Rather than changing environment variables, I have my .tac file set up to add the application directories to sys.path before creating the application instance. It's more convenient to set up test copies without local configuration that way.

Comment: But the location of your source **is** local configuration!